# Go and a bad prime number algorithm

Tags: go, primes

I wrote this prime number sieving algorithm and it doesn't run properly. I can't find the error in the algorithm itself. Could someone help me?

This is what it's supposed to print:

```
[2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29]
```

Versus what it actually prints:

```
[3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 25 29]
```

.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
 var primes = sieve(makeNumbers(29))
 fmt.Printf("%d\n", primes);
}

func makeNumbers(n int) []int {
 var numbers = make([]int, n - 1)
 for i := 0; i < len(numbers); i++ {
  numbers[i] = i + 2
 }
 return numbers
}

func sieve(numbers []int) []int {
 var numCopy = numbers
 var max = numbers[len(numbers)-1]
 var sievedNumbers = make([]int, 0)
 for i := 0; numCopy[i]*numCopy[i] <= max; i++ {
  for j := i; j < len(numCopy); j++ {
   if numCopy[j] % numCopy[i] != 0 || j == i {
    sievedNumbers = append(sievedNumbers, numCopy[j])
   }
  }
  numCopy = sievedNumbers
  sievedNumbers = make([]int, 0) 
 }
 return numCopy
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be "for j := 0" rather than "for j := i".